# Why do phase space representations satisfy a covariance property?

Tags: continuous-variable, representation-theory, phase-space

In ([*Ferrie and Emerson 2008*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2658)), the authors define (Definition 2 in page 5 of the arxiv) a generic *quasi-probability representation* of quantum states as any map $\operatorname{Herm}(\mathcal H)\to L^2(\Gamma,\mu)$ that is linear and invertible. Here, $\Gamma$ is some set with positive measure $\mu$, and $L^2(\Gamma,\mu)$ is the space of square-integrable functions on $\Gamma$.
I understand this definition as a generalisation of the standard notion of [quasiprobability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution): every state $\rho$ (or more generally any Hermitian operator) is mapped to a function defined on some domain where we can take integrals. So far so good.

The authors then make the following observation:

> Given this definition, any phase space representation is then a particular type of quasi-probability representation. In particular, if there exists symmetry group on $\Gamma$, $G$, carrying a unitary representation $\hat U:G\to \mathrm U(\mathcal H)$ and a quasi-probability representation satisfying the covariance property $\hat U_g \hat A \hat U_g^\dagger\mapsto \{ A(g(\alpha))\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$ for all $\hat A\in\operatorname{Herm}(\mathcal H)$ and $g\in G$, then $\hat A\mapsto A(\alpha)$ is a *phase space representation*. All phase space functions (that we are aware of) in the literature correspond to quasi-probability representations that satisfy this additional covariance condition.

If I'm reading this correctly, we are saying that all standard quasiprobability representations (Wigner, $P$, $Q$, etc) satisfy this "covariance property" for some underlying symmetry group.
However, this is not stated explicitly, so I'm not sure. I'm also not sure whether these "phase space representations" do indeed correspond to the more "standard" quasiprobability distributions.

If this is what is meant with phase space representations, how do we see that the standard known quasiprobability distributions ($P,Q$, Wigner) satisfy this covariance property? And what are the underlying symmetry groups?
Otherwise, what are examples of such phase space representations?